# PL/SQL: ORA-00907 : Error in Bulk collect

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, bulk-collect

Is there a way that we use the `distinct` & alias (`as`), to achieve the  bulk collect query as below.

```
SELECT  distinct OBJ_TEST  ( EMP_ID as E1, EMP_NAME)
BULK COLLECT INTO LVOB_TEST
FROM TMP_EMP ;
```

Comment: what is OBJ_TEST about?

Comment: It is an object type, The bulk collect statement is a part of a pipelined function.

`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SBGMCS.OBJ_TEST AS OBJECT ( EMP_ID NUMBER(10), EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(100) ) ;`

Comment: So what is `E1`; what is the structure of `TMP_EMP`, and how is `LVOb_TEST` defined? Some context would be helpful...

Comment: You are returning a set of `obj_test` objects, so if you really want to name that (though you don't have to), it would be something like `select distinct obj_test(emp_id,emp_name) as person`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way that we use the distinct & alias (as), to achieve the
>   bulk collect query as below.

Not sure why you want to alias since it doesnot make sense to take alias while `bulk collect` and use it. You will always have to use the `column names` of the Object which you defined. See below and read my inline comments:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_TEST AS OBJECT ( EMP_ID NUMBER(10), EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(100) ) ;

    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE V_OBJ_TYP IS TABLE OF OBJ_TEST;
    /

    CREATE TABLE TMP_EMP  ( EMP_ID NUMBER(10), EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(100) );
    /

    INSERT INTO TMP_EMP  VALUES (1,        'XXX');
    INSERT INTO TMP_EMP  VALUES (2,        'HHH');
    INSERT INTO TMP_EMP  VALUES (3,        'ZZZ');
    INSERT INTO TMP_EMP  VALUES (4,        'YYY');
    /
    COMMIT;
    /

    DECLARE
         LVOB_TEST                     V_OBJ_TYP;
    BEGIN
        --See below how you can use the alias but it doesnot make sense 
        --since you cannot use the alias name while displaying the result using alias name.
         SELECT OBJ_TEST (EP_ID, E_NAME)
         BULK COLLECT INTO LVOB_TEST
           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID AS EP_ID, 
                                 EMP_NAME AS E_NAME
                            FROM TMP_EMP);

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('EMP_ID'||'--' ||'EMP_NAME');

         FOR I IN 1 .. LVOB_TEST.COUNT
         LOOP   
          --Here am displaying the result of the query. But i cannot use alias since i need can only refer the name of the columns defined in the Object. i.e. EMP_ID & EMP_NAME. 
          --IF you want to use that alias then create the object with that alias name.      
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (LVOB_TEST (I).EMP_ID ||'--' ||LVOB_TEST (I).EMP_NAME );
         END LOOP;
    END;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
EMP_ID--EMP_NAME
4--YYY
2--HHH
3--ZZZ
1--XXX

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very light on detail, but at a guess, you want:

```
SELECT  distinct OBJ_TEST  ( EMP_ID , EMP_NAME)
BULK COLLECT INTO LVOB_TEST
from
 ( select distinct emp_id, emp_name from tmp_emp )
```